# Fluent Data Builder with base class, passing in non-static argument into the base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, base-class

Base Class

```
public abstract class AbstractAuditBuilder
{
    private readonly AbstractAudit builder;

    protected AbstractAuditBuilder(AbstractAudit builder)
    {
        this.builder = builder;
        this.builder.CreatedId = 1;
        this.builder.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    }

    public AbstractAuditBuilder WithCreatedId(int createdId)
    {
        builder.CreatedId = createdId;
        return this;
    }
```

Derived class

```
public class SaleGroupBuilder : AbstractAuditBuilder
{
    private static readonly SaleGroup saleGroup = new SaleGroup();

    public SaleGroupBuilder() : base(saleGroup)
    {
        saleGroup.SaleGroupId = 1;
        saleGroup.Description = "Miscellaneous";
    }   

 public SaleGroupBuilder WithSaleGroupId(int saleGroupId)
    {
        saleGroup.SaleGroupId = saleGroupId;
        return this;
    }

private SaleGroup Build()
    {
        return saleGroup;
    }

    public static implicit operator SaleGroup(SaleGroupBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Using the above

```
public class SeedSaleGroup
{
    public static void Seed(ContextMaster context)
    {
        context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder().WithSaleGroupId(1));
        context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder().WithDescription("Corporates")
        .WithSaleGroupId(2));
        context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder().WithDescription("Insurance")
        .WithSaleGroupId(3));
        context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder().WithDescription("Removals")
        .WithSaleGroupId(4));
        context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder().WithDescription("Self Storage")
        .WithSaleGroupId(5));
        context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder().WithDescription("Storage")
        .WithSaleGroupId(6));
    }
}
```

Now when I call context.SaveChanges() with Entity Framework 6, it is going to save only the last item, so in the database there is only one record which is a sale group with description “Storage”. I believe that this is caused by the fact that my SaleGroupBuilder class is creating static readonly SaleGroup, however if I remove the keyword static I get the following error:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

I have tried this: 
    public class SaleGroupBuilder : AbstractInformationBuilder
    {
        private readonly SaleGroup saleGroup;

```
    public SaleGroupBuilder(SaleGroup saleGroup) : base(saleGroup)
    {
        this.saleGroup = saleGroup;
        saleGroup.SaleGroupId = 1;
        saleGroup.Description = "Miscellaneous";
    }
```

And then I used it like this:

```
public class SeedSaleGroup
{
public static void Seed(ContextMaster context)
{
    context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder(new SaleGroup()).WithSaleGroupId(1));
    context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder(new SaleGroup()).WithDescription("Corporates")
    .WithSaleGroupId(2));
    context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder(new SaleGroup()).WithDescription("Insurance")
    .WithSaleGroupId(3));
    context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder(new SaleGroup()).WithDescription("Removals")
    .WithSaleGroupId(4));
    context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder(new SaleGroup()).WithDescription("SelfStorage")
    .WithSaleGroupId(5));
    context.SaleGroup.Add(new SaleGroupBuilder(new SaleGroup()).WithDescription("Storage")
    .WithSaleGroupId(6));
}
}
```

This worked, and inserted all records to the database, but I don’t want to be passing new SaleGroup()each time, is there any other way to achieve this?
This is my first post ever so please ask if I didn’t explain something properly. 
Thank you.

Comment: Why, *why*, ***why*** do you combine a `static` field with a non-static class, set it in the constructor and pass the very same value to the base class, ultimately storing in an instance field? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have a static field in there because I cannot pass a non-static field into my base class,so if I keep it like this                                                                    public class SaleGroupBuilder : AbstractInformationBuilder
    {
        private readonly SaleGroup saleGroup;
        
        public SaleGroupBuilder() : base(saleGroup)
        {           
            saleGroup.SaleGroupId = 1;
            saleGroup.Description = "Miscellaneous"; }                                                                   I get: An object reference is required for the non-static field

Comment: The problems seems that they all have the same `Id`.

Comment: @user3173203 Lol, of course an “object reference is required”! You cannot dereference uninitialized stuff! The *primary* issue is *not* the field being either static or instance, but **being uninitialized**.

Comment: sorry, i just spotted that i pasted this wrong. public class SaleGroupBuilder : AbstractInformationBuilder { private readonly SaleGroup saleGroup = new SaleGroup(); public SaleGroupBuilder() : base(saleGroup) { saleGroup.SaleGroupId = 1; saleGroup.Description = "Miscellaneous"; } gives the same error message

Comment: @BartoszKP in my example they all will be set to 1 however in the actual code im changing the Id field

Comment: @user3173203 I think you should present the actual code you're having trouble with. Otherwise you expect everyone to guess what other things are happening.

Comment: @BartoszKP I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously each call to your factory modified one and the same object:

```
private static readonly SaleGroup saleGroup = new SaleGroup();
```

You should create new object each time new factory is started up:

```
public class SaleGroupBuilder : AbstractAuditBuilder
{
    private readonly SaleGroup saleGroup = new SaleGroup();

    public SaleGroupBuilder() : base(saleGroup)
    {
        saleGroup.SaleGroupId = 1;
        saleGroup.Description = "Miscellaneous";
    }

//...
```

Not sure what's with the `base` call - it looks as it shouldn't compile in your example, but that's probably another detail you've omitted. Or maybe you just use misleading name - `builder` instead of a `objectBeingBuilt`.

Comment: I've tried this, and this gives me the error, An object reference is required for a non-static field, method, or property. So this is why i marked the saleGroup static, because then it compiles, but at the same time, it only saves one item into the database. So, I dont know how to make it work properly.

Comment: @user3173203 No, you didn't. Compare your and mine version carefully.

Comment: @user3173203 Surely it doesn't throw NRE. So, what is it now?

Comment: it says "An object reference is reuired for the non-static field,method or property". With the exact copy of your code.

Answer (score 0):

May I just add, as this is a project we're working on together, that the aim here is to create many different data builders, one per object, and each object when defined inherits from a base class as most of the objects have the same properties of CreatedId, CreatedOn, ModifiedId, ModifiedOn, for example. We ideally within our data builders don't want to repeat the methods WithCreatedId, WithCreatedOn, WithModifiedId, WithModifiedOn for each data builder, as we don't want to repeat ourselves, hence the decision to have a base class. But it would seem that we can only use the base class if we new-up our object as a static, unless someone can provide further insight into a different way. HTH to shed some further light on the issue :)

Comment: Are you the same user as @adminSoftDK?